# double integral to find the volume

Tags: integration, volume

i have to find the integral above a triangle with vertices (0,2), (1,1) and (2,2) and under the surface z=xy. I understand the concept of using the double integral to find the volume, but my issue is to set the limits for my integral. Finding the lines passing through (0,2)->(1,1) and (2,2)->(1,1) gives me the lines y = -x+2 and y=x. My problem now is: do i use x = 2-y and x = y as the limits, or y = -x+2 and y=x. It gives a different integral. I hope my question is somehow clear. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You must fix, for instance, some $y\in[1,2]$ and find the interval of variation of $x$ corresponding to that $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $y∈[1,2]$ and find the interval of variation of $x$ corresponding to that $y$, as in the following picture.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand the approach, but I don't seem to understand when to pick what variation; x over y or y over x. In this picture, using a variation of y corresponding to that x would give the same result ? My brain hurts, it bothers me.

Comment: Yes, using a variation of $y$ corresponding to $x$ would give the same result, but you should consider two different expressions: $y=2-x$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $y=x$ for $x\in[1,2]$. Computing the integral would be slightly more complicated.